# jQuery DatePicker's years dropdown is empty in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

The following setup works in IE9-, Chrome and FireFox.

Why does IE8 fail to load the years dropdown with values ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var now = new Date('2014,01,08');
    var maxDate = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear() - 18, now.getUTCMonth(),     now.getUTCDate());
    var minDate = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear() - 99, now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate());

    $('.birthdateDatePicker').datepicker({ 
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '-99:-18',
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        minDate: minDate, 
        maxDate: maxDate,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonText: '',
        buttonImage: '/media/7772/schedule_16.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function () {
            this.fireEvent && this.fireEvent('onchange') || $(this).change();
        },
    });

    $('.birthdateDatePicker').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
});
```

Comment: What version of `jQuery` are you using?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GQDJ9/4/
I can't see the results in my own IE8 browser though .

Comment: Sadly, jsfiddle doesn't seem to support IE8 at all. Does it work if you remove the trailing comma in your options object?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario that's true. I forgot about this little "issue" between jsFiddle and IE < 9.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

The minDate and maxDate don't seem to work in IE8.

Change the code to:

```
..
minDate: "-99y", 
maxDate: "-18y",
..
```